# Is there a way to randomly apply css properties from a list to a bunch of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

More exactly could i apply to my 20 divs, 10 background-images that i have, so there are two elements with same background?
I want to reproduce a game and i didn't start beacause i don't know if it's possible. I have 20 cards faced upside down. When i click one they flip and show their image. But they are in pairs. So when you clicked the second and their image don't match they flip back. So you have to  keep their position in mind until you match them all. If, you fliped first and the second you fliped have the same background-image, they remain with face up. But for now i want just to know if that manner of applying css it's possible. The ideea is to have background-images at different positions at every reload.

Comment: No code, no chocolate! What have you tried?

Comment: since your question is very vague, i can only say: "yes its possible"

Comment: For each of your ten background images, randomly select two of the divs and apply the relevant CSS style to them, then exclude those from the next iteration.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut Yes, it's possible to do.

Comment: `element.style.backgroundImage = "url(path_to_image)";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Create an array containing 10 items, one for each of your background-images.

```
var bg_array = [
    'img01.jpg',     //replace property here with URL of your image
    // ... repeat
    'img10.jpg'
];
```

Next, create an array with a loop that will contain all the actual background images you want, i.e. 20, or 10 pairs in this case.

```
var i = bg_array.length,
    tempArray = [];
while (i) {
    i -= 1;
    tempArray.push(bg_array[i]);     // first instance
    tempArray.push(bg_array[i]);     // second instance... makes a pair
}
```

Then loop through your divs and select from this array randomly to assign the URLs to the `backgroundImage` property of each of your divs, deleting instances of URL from the `tempArray` as you go.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),    // this will capture all divs on the page; you might want to be more specific
    d,
    r;
for (d in divs) {     // assume the variable divs is a collection of all your divs
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempArray.length);     // randomly select number based on size of array
    if (divs[d].style) {     // check the div has a style to change!
        d.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + tempArray[r] + '")';     // apply randomly selected background image
        tempArray.splice(r, 1);     // remove image URL from tempArray so this won't be used again (remembering tempArray has 2 of each)
    }
}
```

Hopefully something like this will do what you need.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pUHcf/ here is a test on your js. what i missunderstood?

Comment: I've adjusted the code now, based on your JSFiddle. There were a couple of mistakes, which I've corrected. One thing that wasn't a mistake was the fact that `divs` was not defined; you would ordinarily need to define this yourself based on the elements you are trying to capture. That's the main part you misunderstood. For now, I've defined this for you so it would work for JSFiddle. Update JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wDsXb/1).

Comment: PS. Note that the images you referenced are quite big so a couple of the divs in the JSFiddle will look blank--this because it's only showing you the top-left of the image. You will need to change the images or the CSS for that. I recommended downsizing the images to speed up the page loading.

Answer (score 0):

The html code would be:

```
<div id="1" class="b1"></div>
<div id="2" class="b1"></div>
<div id="3" class="b2"></div>
<div id="4" class="b2"></div>
<div id="5" class="b3"></div>
<div id="6" class="b3"></div>
<div id="7" class="b4"></div>
<div id="8" class="b4"></div>
<div id="9" class="b5"></div>
<div id="10" class="b5"></div>
```

and the css:

```
.b1{background:url(image1.png);}
.b2{background:url(image2.png);}
.b3{background:url(image3.png);}
.b4{background:url(image4.png);}
.b5{background:url(image5.png);}
```